What is this show folding beginning code park feature of vscode, how to turn if off?

What is this feature that helps showing the line 4,5,6 , I know it trying to help me get a sense of what is current folded part beginning, but I don't want this feature, what is the name of this feature and how to turn if off?

Thank you @wjandrea , I got my answer.
